# DataBinding error -DataGridView in Winforms

Tags: winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I'm new to VB.NET, Windows Application, and DataGridView.
This is a very basic error which I'm suffering now. I have a stored procedure to retrieve  data from the database. I stored those data in a DataSet and tried to view it in a DataGridView. I used this code for databinding which is throwing the error:

```
DataGridView1.DataSource=ds

DataGridView1.DataBindings()
```

The second line in the code is throwing an error:

`Property access must assign to the property or use its value.`

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you meant:

<strike>DataGridView1.DataSource=ds</strike>

<strike>DataGridView1.DataBind()</strike>

**EDIT :**

You haven't provided enough code to check that everything is in place, but I suggest you work your way through this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z.aspx

Comment: No. It is not working. It is throwing an error like "DataBind is not a member of DataGridView"

Comment: Thank u., The link looks helpful.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `DataGridView1.DataBindings()` when dealing with Winforms, it's practical in Webforms.

Just remove the last line and leave the following:

```
DataGridView1.DataSource=ds
```

Answer (score 1):

use `DataGridView1.Databind()`

hope that helped...

Comment: I tried that already. It is not working. It is throwing an error like "DataBind is not a member of DataGridView".